# Disable an apk for certain Android versions through google play console

Tags: android, google-play, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an app that can switch airplane mode on and off on schedule. Or, rather, it could, until Android 4.2 came along, and this setting [became unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422527/modify-airplane-mode-on-on-android-4-2-and-above). My app does not have an android:maxSdkVersion set in the manifest, and I've already started receiving angry emails from users who have Android 4.2 devices. And besides, according to [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747599/android-app-to-be-runned-only-in-2-2-and-2-1-versions), android:maxSdkVersion is probably not the best solution anyway.

I would like to disable my app for Android 4.2+ users, but keep it available for pre-4.2 devices. What would be the best way to do this? Ideally, through the developer console, without having to upload a new apk.

Comment: Do you mean totally disable(uninstallable), or just filter it in Google Play?

Comment: Just filter it. Basically, I want it to be hidden from people who have 4.2. So that they didn't install it just to see that it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it says [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html), and in the question you linked to, setting the `maxSdkVersion` *does* filter it in Google Play, so it won't be seen by devices above that level. That's the only place that checks it, though. Side-loading will still be possible.

The only real problem you'll run into is with people upgrading their OS. If they downloaded it from Play with 4.1, and later upgrade to 4.2, the app won't work correctly.

For those users(and side-loaders), you may want to do a version check on startup. If they fail the check, gracefully tell them what happened in a dialog, etc. Much better than an invisible "it doesn't work anymore!"

Comment: I see. Well, I'll wait a couple more days to see if maybe someone comes up with a different way. And if not, I'll accept your answer.