# Is disabling an application for the new Android versions possible?

Tags: android, google-play

Is disabling an application for newer Android versions (e.g. 4.2 and higher) possible?

I've got an application that Google has rendered useless from 4.2; I don't want users use/install it when they are using Android 4.2 or higher.

Comment: Add in manifest.xml:  <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>

Comment: @ManmeetSinghBatra isn't `android:maxSdkVersion` depricated?

Comment: `android:targetSdkVersion="Max_api_version_which_supported_by_your_app"` would be better. Read http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html for more details.

Comment: @PankajKumar but then they still see the app in store and get disappointed when it doesn't work...

Comment: @ManmeetSinghBatra that doesn't work. Read: http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: targetsdk should work. you should try it. this is working for my app.

Comment: @PankajKumar doesn't work, read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target

Comment: I think you are confused with compatible word. It means when you declaire min to 7 and target to 16, then your app will be tested on 16 but can work on 16, 15, 14 ... to 7. Read carefully and don't be confuse

Comment: @PankajKumar an app with target 16 will run on 17 but in compatibility mode. It will also still show up in play for api 17. Not what I want in short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you want. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) for the deprecated `maxSdkVersion`:

> Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or re-validation. **Google Play will continue to use the attribute as a filter**, however, when presenting users with applications available for download.

So, users could still sideload the app, but it will not appear in Google Play for users above that level. That sounds like what you want. There is no way(since 2.0.1) to completely disable sideloads.

---

Regarding this [note about compilation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#manifest-filters):

> ...and the SDK will not compile if maxSdkVersion is set in an app's manifest.

I had my doubts. After testing it just now, my Eclipse/ADT compiles just fine with `maxSdkVersion=15` set. So I wouldn't worry about that.

---

The answers regarding `targetSdkVersion` are fine for some things, but if you're using something that was *intentionally broken/changed* in a newer API, they won't work at all. For example, no amount of compatibility mode will allow 4.2+ to turn airplane mode on/off programmatically from within a non-root app. It also won't change the new implementation of `SecureRandom`.

If the app really is just completely useless for 4.2 because a key feature was removed, try using `maxSdkVersion`. Using a deprecated method always leaves me with a bad taste, but if they don't offer any sort of functional replacement, sometimes it's the only choice.

However, if you can work around it by changing how you accomplish `<whatever>`, that is by far the best solution.

Comment: Also, see my previous answer to a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15080707/752320

Comment: maxSdkVersion is simply ignored for newer versions so that's not really an option for me. Google broke something for me with 4.2 (automatically disable/enable flight mode) which means my app works perfectly prior but not post 4.2.

Comment: Right, the device ignores it. Google Play still uses it to filter. There is nothing you can do to prevent someone from sideloading it. All you can do in that case is check the version on startup and display a dialog explaining it(or whatever). If you want to filter it from Google Play users, this *will* work.

Comment: Yes I think a dialog is probably the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Previously you could have set `android:maxSdkVersion="integer"` to `17` but after `2.1` it has been deprecated.

You can specify `android:targetSdkVersion="Max_api_version_which_supported_by_your_app"` to API Level: 16(4.1) below than 4.2

Comment: isn't `android:maxSdkVersion` depricated?

Comment: @PankajKumar No for you reference only http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: I think you should read here for your information http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html :D

Comment: @PankajKumar Sure i will :)

Comment: @GauravSharma maxSdkVersion doesn't work from 2.1 and onward as pankaj said.

Comment: The new answer wont work either. As specified by the documentation: "However, if the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect." So the app still runs... just with compatibility... (which doesn't help me)